# Getting path of Amazon s3 object in buildspec.yml

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-codebuild

I have uploaded a file to s3 bucket. I want to use the uploaded file in buildspec.yml

I don't how to specify the path of the bucket in the buildspec.yml.

I tried with the below but didn't worked:

```
arn:aws:s3:::us-east-2:abc/xyz.p12
```

Even tried with:

```
https://abc.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/xyz.p12
```

Please help in finding a solution for getting the correct path of the **s3 bucket in buildspec.yml**.

**Note: I want to use the file in buildspec.yml**

***Here goes relevant section of the buildspec.yml code:***

Here "**abc**" is bucket id & "**xyz.p12**" is the file stored in s3

```
build:
    commands:
      - sfcc-ci client:auth $API_KEY $API_SECRET --renew
      - sfcc-ci code:deploy FUN_SHOP_$CODEBUILD_BUILD_NUMBER.zip -i $SFCC_INSTANCE_NAME -c "arn:aws:s3:::us-east-2:abc/xyz.p12" -p $P12_Password
      - sfcc-ci code:activate FUN_SHOP_$CODEBUILD_BUILD_NUMBER -i $SFCC_INSTANCE_NAME
  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo Build completed on `date`
```

Comment: can you provide relevant section of your buildspec.

Comment: You could try this -> `aws s3 cp s3://abc/xyz.p12` to get a copy of the object stored in `S3`

Comment: @salazarin, tried with the below but it didn't worked.

Comment: @Atulkumar make sure your codebuild role/user has the necessary permission to access the s3 bucket. Also please log the error message you are got during the build.